# Sum of semiartinians modules is preserved under morphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules, homological-algebra

Defining a semiartinian module M as module in which  which every nonzero quotient of it contains a simple submodule and also define

$Sa(M):= \sum \lbrace N \leq M \: | \: \mbox{N is semiartinian} \rbrace$.

Given $\phi: M \to N$ module morphism. I want to prove $\phi (Sa(M)) \leq Sa(N)$. Im burned out trying this for a while, so far I have proved that $Sa(M)$ is semiartinian for every module $M$. Lets suppose an easier case where $Sa(M)=M'$ such $M'$ is semiartinian, so  $M' / L$ has some simple submodule lets say $S_{1} /L$ but I need to prove $\phi(M') \in Sa(N)$ and this is where im stuck.  Any help will be aprecciated, thanks!

Comment: Isn't it rather $\phi(Sa(M))\le Sa(N)$ or $Sa(M)\le\phi^{-1}(Sa(N))$?

Comment: You are totally right! My fault, already corrected that one. Any idea how to prove this? @Berci

Comment: Based on what you claim to have proved, the 'easier case' would solve the general case, right?

Comment: Still cant prove the easier case where I supose $Sa(M)$ has only one summand :S , but I got the intuition proving this it is easier to generalize where $Sa(M)$ has more than one summand of semiartinian submodules @Berci

Comment: You can use the isomorphism theorems to see $\phi(M')$ is semiartinian: its quotients are isomorphic to quotients $M/H$ where $\ker\phi\le H$.

Comment: Nice one! But in this case we are not taking all $\phi$ right? We are just considering $\phi_{|M'}$ (\phi restricted to $M'$) so by first isomophism theorem we got that $\phi(M') \cong M' / Ker(\phi_{| M'})$ and $M' / Ker(\phi_{| M'})$ has simple submodule as $M'$ is semiartinian by hypothesis, proving that $\phi(M')$ is semiartinian submodule of $N$. Is there any flaws in my line of thought? @berci

Comment: No, that's it. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M'\le M$ be semiartinian.
Then, based on the *isomorphism theorems*, $\phi(M')$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $M'$ (namely $M'/\ker(\phi|_{M'})$), moreover each quotient of $\phi(M')$ is isomorphic to some quotient of $M'$.
Hence, all nonzero quotients of $\phi(M')$ have a simple submodule, as those are also (isomorphic to) quotients of the semiartinian $M'$.

Since $\phi(M')\le N$ is semiartinian, by definition of $Sa$, we have $\phi(M')\le Sa(N)$.
Finally, 
$$\phi(Sa(M))\ =\ \phi(\sum_{M'\text{ s.a.}}{M'})\ =\ \sum_{M'\text{ s.a.}}\phi(M')\ \le\ Sa(N)\,.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! All clear! The key was to use the first isomorphism theorem as you mentioned and reduce the problem to an easier one as I suggested I apprecciate your help. Im already working in an equivalence between of semiartinian and artinian when the module is noetherian, wondering if I can count with your help tomorrow? I want to work on that one a little bit more. @berci

Comment: And how did you prove that $Sa(M)$ itself is semiartinian?

Comment: For being honest i got stucked but I know its true since its also an exercise in kasch module theory the chapter of socle and radical, I also reduced the case where $Sa(M):=M_{1} + M_{2}$ where $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ are semiartinian, so what I wanted to prove was that for every quotient of $M_{1}+M_{2} / L$ has some simple submodule but the last one is isomorphic to $M_{1} /L + M_{2}/L$ right? Where each of these quotients has some simple submodules, lets say $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ right?But didnt find the candidate of simple submodule for the required quotient :/ @Berci

Comment: Something like that, yes. I'm not sure you only need to consider finitely many summands.

Comment: You are right, we are in trouble as for infinetely many summands isomorphism theorems may not work out :/ @berci

Comment: Can you show $\phi(\sum_i A_i)=\sum_i\phi(A_i)$ for arbitrary index set and $A_i\le A$ and $\phi:A\to B$? It might be of use.

Comment: Think that works, and using again first isomorphism theorem?  @berci